# How to make a stacked bar plot for percentage of classes per year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, stacked-chart

I need to make a stacked bar plot using this dataset(head):

```py
data = {'model': ['A1', 'A6', 'A1', 'A4', 'A3'],
        'year': [2017, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2019],
        'price': [12500, 16500, 11000, 16800, 17300],
        'transmission': ['Manual', 'Automatic', 'Manual', 'Automatic', 'Manual'],
        'mileage': [15735, 36203, 29946, 25952, 1998],
        'fuelType': ['Petrol', 'Diesel', 'Petrol', 'Diesel', 'Petrol'],
        'tax': [150, 20, 30, 145, 145],
        'mpg': [55.4, 64.2, 55.4, 67.3, 49.6],
        'engineSize': [1.4, 2.0, 1.4, 2.0, 1.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  model  year  price transmission  mileage fuelType  tax   mpg  engineSize
0    A1  2017  12500       Manual    15735   Petrol  150  55.4         1.4
1    A6  2016  16500    Automatic    36203   Diesel   20  64.2         2.0
2    A1  2016  11000       Manual    29946   Petrol   30  55.4         1.4
3    A4  2017  16800    Automatic    25952   Diesel  145  67.3         2.0
4    A3  2019  17300       Manual     1998   Petrol  145  49.6         1.0
```

I would like the years (1997-2021) on x-axis and numbers ranging from 0 to 100 on the y-axis representing percentages. Finally, I would like the three different fuelTypes to be shown in yearly proportions; Petrol, Diesel and Hybrid.

I've already done the following calculations to get my percentages, per fuelType, per year and now I need to put it on a graph:

```
fuel_percentage = round((my_data_frame.groupby(['year'])['fuelType'].value_counts()/my_data_frame.groupby('year')['fuelType'].count())*100, 2)

print(fuel_percentage)
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
year  fuelType
1997  Petrol      100.00
1998  Petrol      100.00
2002  Petrol      100.00
2003  Diesel       66.67
      Petrol       33.33
2004  Petrol       80.00
      Diesel       20.00
2005  Petrol       71.43
      Diesel       28.57
2006  Petrol       66.67
      Diesel       33.33
2007  Petrol       56.25
      Diesel       43.75
2008  Diesel       66.67
      Petrol       33.33
etc...
```

My main worry is that since the object is not a dataframe I won't be able to use it to make a plot.

Here is an example of the kind of plot I would like (*replace players with fuelTypes and y-axis with percentages*):
[image]

Thanks for the help!

...
edit
...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

### `.groupby` & `.unstack`

- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) creates a long dataframe that must be unstacked to a wide form, to easily work with the plotting API

```py
import pandas as pd

# I'm not a fan of this option because it requires doing .groupby twice
# calculate percent with groupby
dfc = (df.groupby(['year'])['fuelType'].value_counts() / df.groupby('year')['fuelType'].count()).mul(100).round(1)

# unstack the long dataframe
dfc = dfc.unstack(level=1)
```

- `.groupby` with `.value_counts` and `.unstack`

```py
dfc = df.groupby(['year'])['fuelType'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).unstack(level=1)
```

### `.crosstab`

- Alternatively, use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a wide dataframe directly

```py
# get the normalized value counts by index
dfc = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.fuelType, normalize='index').mul(100).round(1)
```

### Plot

- Plot the dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with [`kind='bar'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) and `stacked=True`, or with [`kind='area'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.area.html).

```py
# display(dfc)
fuelType  Diesel  Petrol
year                    
2016        50.0    50.0
2017        50.0    50.0
2019         0.0   100.0

# plot bar
ax = dfc.plot(kind='bar', ylabel='Percent(%)', stacked=True, rot=0, figsize=(10, 4))
```

[image]

- Remove `xticks=dfc.index` to have the plotting API have more values on the x-axis.

```py
# plot area
ax = dfc.plot(kind='area', ylabel='Percent(%)', rot=0, figsize=(10, 4), xticks=dfc.index)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer, which worked, much appreciated!

Comment: @JacobMarlo You're welcome, I'm glad this works for you.

Comment: Do you think there is a way for the stackplot to not take up the entire space of the chart and only fill the bottom area of the lines like the example in my question?

Comment: @JacobMarlo the plots in the example are not 100% plots. The filled area matches the percent based on the sum of the values at that index location. If you want each percent to be calculated based on the entire count, then use `dfc = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.fuelType, normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)`.

Comment: this answer seems to have worked, except I still have one minor problem that stays the same... the hybrid line somehow alters in the middle of Diesel and Petrol year by year which is clearly a mistake, considering that Hybrids percentage never goes over 2% throughout the entire dataframe... would you know the reason for that? --- I've edited the bottom of my question and added the picture of the resulting graph I'm talking about for you to better understand. ---

Comment: @JacobMarlo I can't reproduce the issue with the data provided. Also my answer was correct given the original data in the question. If you want a different plot, there should be a new question, with sufficient data to reproduce the issue. Given the data in the OP, there plot will always be 100%, because the total percent for each your is 100%.

Comment: `dfc = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.fuelType, normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)` these percent's are based on **all** of the data for all years, not each individual year. The difference between `normalize='index'` and `normalize=True`